# Change appearance of an disabled button in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I was trying to disable a button if the condition is met. For example if an item is returned, after clicking the return button, the button should be  disabled. What I did was make the button clickable and disabled. Meaning it would not show any validation that an item is being returned. My concern is that how would you change the appearance of the button so that it appears like a disabled button?

One more thing, I also did one code that typically disabled the button, but it was clickable.

```
<tr class="del<?php echo $id ?>">

<td><?php echo $row['equipment_description']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['firstname']." ".$row['lastname']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['student_id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['year_level']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['course']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row['date_borrow']; ?></td> 
<td><?php echo $row['due_date']; ?> </td>
<td><?php echo $row['borrow_status'];?></td>
<td><a rel="tooltip"
       title="Return"
       id="<?php echo $borrow_details_id?>" <?php if(strcmp($row['borrow_status'],"returned")!=0) {echo 'href="#delete_equipments'; echo $borrow_details_id; echo '"';}?>
       data-toggle="modal"
       class="btn btn-success">
    <i class="icon-check icon-large"></i>Return</a><td></td>

<?php include('modal_return.php'); ?>
```

Comment: Poor technique. I recommend using AJAX. Use JavaScript to send data to the server. Use PHP to `echo json_encode($assocArray);` so JavaScript can process JSON upon success. Remember, disabling a button happens on the Client Side.

Comment: Why don't you set your button on a `button` tag instead of an `a`? Then you could just add the `disabled` param

Comment: There's an incorrect `td` element in the last cell: `... </i>Return</a><td></td>`.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your problem is that you are trying to use an `<a>` tag like a button. Since your `<a>` tag doesn't actually direct someone to a new page like a link tag should, why don't you just use the `<button>` tag? It comes with a "disabled" attribute.

```
<td><button rel="tooltip" title="Return" id="<?php echo $borrow_details_id?>" <?php
if(strcmp($row['borrow_status'],"returned")!=0) {echo $borrow_details_id; echo '"';}?>  data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success" disabled><i class="icon-check icon-large"></i>Return</button><td></td>
```

Comment: it did disable the button but i cannot return an item anymore since it is disabled